# #solace Migration from MQ on mainframe to Solace

Tags: mq, solace

We are using mainframe application and from mainframe we write lots of messages to MQ to send to downstream. We are planning to migrate from MQ to Solace on mainframe. Is it possible? Solace supports mainframe applications?

How can we put messages to solace from mainframe batch and online(IMS transactions)?

Thanks,
Praveen.

Answer (score 3):

Solace does not support mainframe applications directly but Solace can be easily integrated with IBM DataPower appliances which can interface with mainframe applications. The DataPower appliance can handle the transformation requirement of the service and the Solace appliance can handle the messaging portion to provide quick and efficient message delivery downstream.

The 'Solace Integration with IBM Datapower' integration guide, available on the Solace Developer Portal, has more information on this:

http://dev.solacesystems.com/integration-guides/ibm-datapower/

You may also be able to use Solace's REST interface, depending on your Mainframe application. Solace's REST interface allows communication using standard POST HTTP requests.

There are also guides for Solace's REST interface available on the Solace Developer Portal:

http://dev.solacesystems.com/docs/open-apis-protocols-docs/

Answer (score 1):

Old thread, but Mainframe is a long lasting tech.

- Solace now provide an open-source bridge for IBM MQ Bridge, so MainFrame<->IBM MQ<->Solace is possible.
- Datapower integration using JMS to connect to Solace is still possible.
  Solace REST Messaging API is still possible.
- And finally OpenLegacy can help here :
  https://www.openlegacy.com/